# Leafletjs legand value = 0

Tags: leaflet, legend

I would like to know (if it's possible) how to add a 0 value ine Leafletjs block's legend.

For an example, this is my class :

```
function getColorPOPULATION(d) {
        return d > 500 ? '#004590' :
               d > 250 ? '#00ABFF' :
               d > 1   ? '#A0E0FF' :
                         '#FFF4D0' ;
```

... and my grades (div legend) :

```
grades = [0, 1, 250, 500],
```

-> I get this result :

```
0 - 1
1 - 250
250 - 500
500+
```

I would like to isolate the 0 value (my first class will be 0). Does Leafletjs able to do this ?

Thank you,